# WinRT/Metro Animation in code-behind

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

The following code works fine in Silverlight:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = 50;
    doubleAnimation.To = 100;
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
    storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, button1);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Width"));
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

In WinRT/Metro it needs one minor change to make it compile:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Width");
```

but when you run it, nothing happens.

If you change the property from "Width" to "Opacity" (also change From=0 and To=1) that works.

What is the problem with "Width"?

Comment: Why haven't you used the `EventTrigger` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx for moving all this code to xaml?

Comment: @RredCat - As far as I know we don't have EventTrigger in WinRT.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
doubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
```

That seems to fix the problem.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807#dependent explains the reason

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but try to use:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, Button.WidthProperty);
```

Instead of

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Width");
```